# YouTube data api search, exclude videos with ads

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I was wondering if there is a way when I am quering the api for videos to exclude those who have advertisments.

Also I would like to filter out the videos that are not available for my location which might change according to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to filter out videos that are monetized.

The [restriction parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#restrictionsp) can be used to filter out videos that are not playable due to geographic restrictions, based on the IP address of the client that will be playable.